# Suppress mFilter onLoad message

Tags: r

I'm creating an R package and it cannot show any kind of message from imported packages when it loads. I'm having a problem with an specific package, mFilter. If I import it, I always get

```
‘mFilter’ version: 0.1-3

 ‘mFilter’ is a package for time
 series filtering

 See ‘library(help="mFilter")’ for
 details

 Author: Mehmet Balcilar,
 mbalcilar@yahoo.com
```

when the user loads my package, regardless of adding suppressMessages('mFilter') in the .onLoad file.

I really need to use mFilter. So removing it from Imports list doesn't help. Does anyone know what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. In the `mFilter` package, instead of using `message()` in `.onLoad()`, the authors have incorrectly used

```
if(interactive() || getOption("verbose"))
    writeLines(strwrap(txt, indent = 4, exdent = 4))
```

If you are using the package interactively this will always execute and won't be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can limit your use of `mFilter` to just a few functions, you could *Suggest* `mFilter` rather than Import or Depend on it. Then, in the functions that need it, you could `capture.output(require(mFilter, quietly = TRUE))` to load the package (and `stop` with a message that `mFilter` needs to be installed if the load is unsuccessful).

Alternately, you could take the same approach, but have the loading of `mFilter` take place in your package's `.onLoad`.

You may even be able to do something tricky where `mFilter` is listed in `DESCRIPTION` Imports (to guarantee it gets installed) but *isn't* imported in the `NAMESPACE` file. It would probably (at least) throw a warning during check, but it would probably work just fine.